# CakePHP query in query

Tags: php, cakephp

How i can write this query in cakePHP (v2.5)

```html
SELECT count(*)
      FROM websites
      WHERE view > (SELECT view
                   FROM websites
                   WHERE id = 212)
```

Comment: please mention what you have tried ?

Comment: I try lot of thing what i delete when i saw that doesn t work but i still have this :

$this->Website->find('all', array(    
    
     'conditions' => array('view >' => $this->Website->find('all', array(                  
                  'conditions' => array('id >' =>'212' )))),
     'order' => array('Website.id DESC'),
     'group' =>'Website.id',
     'limit' => 1,
     'offset' => 0
     ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
 $this->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array('websites.view > SELECT view FROM websites WHERE id = 212')
));
```

please have a look at the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)